# How do I get and If else to display a Messagebox from a class

Tags: winforms, class, messagebox

I'm learning c# Windows Form App and I've been working on a simple application that is to prompt a user to enter their name, click a button then display what they entered in a messagebox and to display an error message if they leave the field blank. I'm using a class and method to handle this logic.
I got the first part working, but i cannot get the error message to work. I thought about using if / else since that's what i've seen on other posts but I can't get it to work. I get all kinds of errors, the current one i get in the class is:

> Error 1   An object of a type convertible to 'string' is required

Here is the code:

```
// Form1.cs



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string in_name;


     in_name = Console.ReadLine();
        Class1 name = new Class1();


        MessageBox.Show(name.GetName("Name: " + inputName.Text));
    }
}
}



// Class1.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class Class1
    {
        //Declaring identifiers:

        string yourName;


        // Methods 

        public string GetName(string in_name) 
        {
            if (in_name == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You must enter a name");
                return;
            }
            else
            {

                return yourName = in_name;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @ChrisF line 1 on the class file

Answer (score 0):

You must return something from your `GetName` method.

Change your method to this

```
public string GetName(string in_name) 
{
    if (in_name == null)
    {
        return "You must enter a name";
    }
    else
    {
        return yourName = in_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran it, i don't get the error but the method bypasses the if/else. It displays the messageboc "Name:  ".

Comment: Thank you, I edited but it keeps bypassing the condition (no error shown). I'm doing this inside the GetName method in my Class1.cs

Comment: I feel the problem is not in the method but in the MessageBox.Show code in Form1.cs. Yet, I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Start from the begin, what exactly you trying to do?

Comment: I want the application to pop a message saying "You must enter a name" if the field is left blank and 'Done' button is pressed. If user enter a name and presses 'Done', a pop message will display the name he entered.

Comment: Also, your writing a WinForm application but using `Console.ReadLine();`. I'm not 100% sure but I don't thinks thats possible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4994/discussion-between-ash-burlaczenko-and-oskar)

Comment: Well, the app displays the name entered successfully. The problem is the error message. Are you running it?